# Which is faster of two case or if?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, if-statement, switch-statement

I have to make a "very" light script which would take in options from user and call in functions within the script to perform some tasks.

Now I can us both IF and CASE options, but I want to know which among both will be lighter. CASE obviously looks less complex when I put it in script, does it make my script lighter as well in terms of computation/CPU usage/memory usage or IF is better ?

The script will have around 10-15 input options to select from, the no. of option for choosing might increase in future, if new functionality gets added.

Note:- It's for usage in bash running on Solaris 10/RHEL 6

Comment: I don't think it makes a difference. If in doubt, measure it.

Comment: Do these little details really matter when you've already paid the cost of starting bash?

Comment: The difference on how CASE and IF will be turned into actual machine instructions will be wildly insignificant if you use something as inefficient as shell scripting.

Comment: Is using bash / shell scripting that bad ?

Comment: There are too many variables involved (how long is your code, what input will it use, what does it *do*) to provide any meaningful answer to this question.

Comment: Usually the slowest thing in a shell script is process creation -- starting external commands and creating subshells. Every single non-builtin command in a script is slower than that if/case block you're worrying about. If you're trying to make a script faster, minimizing process creation is orders of magnitude more important than any possible difference between if and case structures. And switching to something like perl or python that can do most things without creating any additional processes at all...

Answer (score 10):

Although I agree with other comments that bash is itself slow, I just executed some tests here to check the difference. Platform is Ubuntu 10.10 on a slow machine. No other processes running in parallel.

CASE is taking less than half the time, which is quite surprising:

```
user@machine:~$ time for i in {1..1000000}; do if [ "$i" == "45"  ]; then echo $i; elif [ "$i" == "50" ]; then echo $i; fi; done
45
50

real    0m22.154s
user    0m21.750s
sys     0m0.380s

user@machine:~$ time for i in {1..1000000}; do case "$i" in "45") echo $i;; "50") echo $i;; esac; done
45
50

real    0m10.286s
user    0m10.230s
sys     0m0.040s
```

Repeating the experiment, but adding a third comparison:

```
user@machine:~$ time for i in {1..1000000}; do if [ "$i" == "45"  ]; then echo $i; elif [ "$i" == "50" ]; then echo $i; elif [ "$i" == "6000" ]; then echo $i; fi; done
45
50
6000

real    0m32.602s
user    0m32.070s
sys     0m0.510s

user@machine:~$ time for i in {1..1000000}; do case "$i" in "45") echo $i;; "50") echo $i;; "6000") echo $i;; esac; done
45
50
6000

real    0m13.553s
user    0m13.520s
sys     0m0.010s
```

It looks like IF simply repeats a comparison 3 times while CASE makes a single comparison, which could explain why CASE is almost constant while IF seems to take a time that is proportional to the number of comparisons.

Now checking the suggested [[ $i == 45 ]]:

```
user@machine:~$ time for i in {1..1000000}; do if [[ $i == 45  ]]; then echo $i; elif [[ $i == 50 ]]; then echo $i; elif [[ $i == 6000 ]]; then echo $i; fi; done
45
50
6000

real    0m15.127s
user    0m15.090s
sys     0m0.010s

user@machine:~$ time for i in {1..1000000}; do case $i in 45) echo $i;; 50) echo $i;; 6000) echo $i;; esac; done
45
50
6000

real    0m9.966s
user    0m9.940s
sys     0m0.010s
```

Again, CASE is faster, but not that faster.

To try to determine the time wasted on the FOR-LOOP itself, let's try to run almost nothing:

```
user@machine:~$ time for i in {1..1000000}; do x=0; done

real    0m5.095s
user    0m5.070s
sys     0m0.010s
```

Comment: You'll significantly speed up the `if` method if you use `[[ $i = 45 ]]` (with no quotes). I'm not exactly sure what this benchmark means, though...

Comment: Seconded. You are comparing `if test`, not just `if`.

Comment: Added more tests with your suggestions. Also, tried to estimate the amount of time wasted by the FOR-loop.

Comment: Note that `[ ]` is only a little bit slower than `[[ ]]`, but it much faster than `/bin/[` (aka `/bin/test`) because `[` is still a bash builtin. I tried using `/bin/test` instead, and it ran about 200x slower than even the `[ ]` version. As I said, process creation for external commands matters much more than the distinctions being tested here.

Comment: Yes. Differences between IF and CASE will hardly matter. Usually, shell scripts suffer from poor performance because they keep calling external programs to do most of the heavy lifting: sed, awk, you name it. But this IF versus CASE comparison was what the OP was questioning. Nevertheless, IF proved to be much slower than CASE in a consistent way.