# Better way then having multiple elif statement

Tags: bash, if-statement

I have a file called file.txt which has some random numbers from 1 to 100. So a script reads the file and executes a bunch of commands and print some statements.

One way of achieving the result could be something like these but having 100 `if` and `elif` statement in a script doesn't look so nice.

```
for i in `cat file.txt`; do
  echo "Displaying" $i
    if [[ $i = 1 ]]; then
        echo "blah blah blah for" $i
        command1
        command2
    elif [[ $i = 2 ]]; then
        echo "blah blah blah for" $i
        command3
        command4
        command5
    elif [[ $i = 3 ]]; then
        echo "blah blah blah for" $i
        command6
        command7
    elif [[ $i = 4 ]]; then
        echo "blah blah blah for" $i
        command8
        command9
        command10
    elif [[ $i = 5 ]]; then
        echo "blah blah blah for" $i
        command11
        command12
        command13
        command14
    elif [[ $i = 6 ]]; then
        echo "blah blah blah for" $i
        command15

        ....
        ....
        ....
        ....
        ....
        ....
    elif [[ $i = 99 ]]; then
        echo "blah blah blah for" $i
        command310
        command311
        command312
        command313
        command314
    elif [[ $i = 100 ]]; then
        echo "blah blah blah for" $i
        command315
    fi
done
```

Is there any better or smarter way to do these on bash

Comment: I'd start with a `case` statement `case $i in 1) ... ;; 2) ... ;; ... ;; 99) ... ;; esac`.

Comment: @JosephLi write comments with unicorn emojis between `elif`s then it will look nice

Answer (score 3):

Classic case of `case`:

```
case "$i" in
    1)
        echo "blah blah blah for" $i
        command1
        command2
        ;;
    […]
    *)
        echo "Unhandled value $i" >&2
        exit 2
esac
```

In addition to this:

- [Use a `while` loop](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) to process lines
- [Use More Quotes™](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to make use of a `case` statement. It is the bash version of what is known in programming as the [switch statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement). They are generally faster then an if-then-else statement as they are most likely implemented with a lookup table or hash-list.

> Additionally, an optimized implementation may execute much faster than the alternative, because it is often implemented by using an indexed branch table. For example, deciding program flow based on a single character's value, if correctly implemented, is vastly more efficient than the alternative, reducing instruction path lengths considerably. When implemented as such, a switch statement essentially becomes a perfect hash.
>
> source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement)

An interesting comparison can be found here: [Which is faster of two case or if?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20018037/which-is-faster-of-two-case-or-if)

To address your code, you're loop of the form

```
for i in $(cat file); do
  ...
done
```

should be rewritten. As you read the file word-by-word, you should write something like:

```
while read -r line; do
   for i in $line; do
     ...
   done
done < file
```

You're if-then-else is then rewritten as:

```
case "$i" in
   1) command1; command2; command3 ;;
   2) command4; command5; command6 ;;
   ...
   100) command315; command316;;
esac
```

Comment: Bash case statements are not optimised even when it is possible (and since the options are subject to parameter expansion, it may well not be possible. So they aren't much faster, but they are easier to write (and read). They are a little faster basically because they don't require the [/[[ commands to be interpreted.

Comment: @rici According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20018037/which-is-faster-of-two-case-or-if there is a clear difference.

Comment: yes, but the difference is much more marked for the `[` command than for the `[[` builtin. It has nothing to do with lookup tables or indexed lookups.

Comment: @rici On my current system I still have a 1/3 speedup using `case` instead of `[[ ... ]]]`

Comment: You mean it's 33% faster, right? A hash table would be much faster, since it wouldn't require more than one test.